# Can Flow Type tighten method definition of an instance in method chaining

Tags: typescript, flowtype

I'm writing a Node.js module with being Flow typed which looks like this.

```
hole(obj)
    .pipe(fn1)
    .pipe(fn2)
    .pipe(fn3);
```

And the expected type definition is *something like* this.

```
/* Not working */
hole(T)
    .pipe((T) => U)
    .pipe((U) => V)
    .pipe((V) => W)
```

But I'm really not sure that typing can be possible.

Currently, the function are defined as `pipe(fn: (any => any)): Hole`. I think I need to narrow down the `any` type to be more specific that the functions actually return. The following is what I tried to tighten type definition of method of the instance, but I failed.

```
/* Not working */
class Hole {
    pipe(fn: (T => U)): (Hole & {pipe: (U => V)}))
}
```

Is is possible in JavaScript type tools? If Type Script can instead of Flow, I'll become a Type Script-er. I'm also interested in how Java's Stream solves this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible both in Typescript and Flow. Here's a TypeScript version:

```
declare class Hole<T> {
    constructor(p: T);
    pipe<R>(fn: (p: T) => R): Hole<R>;
}

new Hole(42)
    .pipe(p => p.toString())
    .pipe(p => parseInt(p))
    .pipe(p => [p])
    .pipe(p => p.length)
```

**[Typescript Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20class%20Hole%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(p%3A%20T)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20pipe%3CR%3E(fn%3A%20(p%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20R)%3A%20Hole%3CR%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Hole(42)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.pipe(p%20%3D%3E%20p.toString())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.pipe(p%20%3D%3E%20parseInt(p))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.pipe(p%20%3D%3E%20%5Bp%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.pipe(p%20%3D%3E%20p.length))**

**[Flow demo](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwBIHsIgDwBUA+eAbwCh5LFMA7ZAFxgFcx7MYAKABwC558AlHyw4ChANwUqXAJZc8AJUIcAZjT7c+g+AF5iCoRmyKJZAL5kyNEAHcjODgBYATAKmUAdLPnddxLh5sAMqMMjQA5hwCblTwXnIgvnrwXLDIIACSNPTc0e5x3olcfvAA2lwAujFU8T7FyQE4EfQAFgJAA)**

Comment: Yeah, I'd been surprised if it didn't, but I have never used Flow myself.

Comment: @Tao You are amazing, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.